# How to have whatsapp like camera integration in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project where i need to take images from within the application and then upload it to the server.I want the user to be able to confirm whether the image is accepted or not like in whatsapp.What i have tried till now is to use a surfaceview.The code is shown below:

```
package com.example.surfaceviewcamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    boolean mPreviewRunning;
    Button btncapture;
    String fullPath;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btncapture=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btncapture);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        btncapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);

            }
        });

    }
     Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData .length);
                       saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image stored succesfully at "+fullPath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        };
        public void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
            //image=scaleCenterCrop(image,200,200);
             fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
            try
            {
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
            }
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(fullPath, "photo_marina200000.jpg");

            if(file.exists())
            file.delete();

            file.createNewFile();
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // 100 means no compression, the lower you go, the stronger the compression
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);

            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
            }
            }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera=Camera.open();
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }  if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
            int h) {
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = false;
        mCamera.release();

    }

}
```

the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SurfaceView
 android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="10dip"
android:layout_weight="1">
</SurfaceView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CAPTURE IMAGE"
    android:id="@+id/btncapture"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The requirement is that the user should not use the default camera app of the phone.That is why i have used a surfaceview.My question is as how to have a confirmation and rejection button like whatsapp.Can anyone suggest better ways than what i have done above?

Comment: What you're doing seems good: capture the picture -> save it on disk. Now you need to display the image in an activity/fragment/dialog and ask the user if it's OK or not. If not -> delete the image from disk and come back to the MainActivity.
PS: add a screenshot of the feature in Whatsapp, it will be clearer ;)